# GPU vs integrated graphics hardware, browser canvas fingerprinting, and multi- or dual-boot systems

Tags: linux, web-browser, browser-extensions, fingerprinting, dual-boot

My goal is to ensure that two operating systems installed side-by-side on the same device are unable to return the same **canvas** fingerprint, when a modern browser is allowed to run javascript without any anti-fingerprint restrictions in place.

- this question is [with respect to canvas fingerprinting](https://fingerprintjs.com/blog/canvas-fingerprinting/), whereby an adversary uniquely identifies the hardware in use by measuring the variabilities in how a specified image winds up being rendered by the hardware in use
- I want to ensure that two separate users' respective activity is discrete, and that these users can't be linked through their device, when they are able to run a modern auto-update browser with no anti-fingerprinting strategies active
- anti-fingerprinting strategies include software such as uMatrix or uBlock origin, built-in anti-fingerprinting of the kind that Firefox provides out of the box, XYZ-Fingerprint Defender browser plugins, et al.

I think if one operating system was using the integrated CPU graphics (eg. Intel HD Graphics) while the other was using the onboard alternative GPU, then these fingerprints would be different - is this assumption true?

Will the use of different device drivers, configured to use the same hardware, but on different operating systems, display the same properties and therefore the same fingerprint?

(For example, one OS may use the NVIDIA drivers, while the other used the Nouveau drivers.)

Comment: All of this sounds like a need for testing. Have you determined that the canvas fingerprint is the same? Your whole question seems to depend on the results of this simple test.

Comment: yes that's a fair point - I'll update this once I've reached that state